# How to restrict drawables only shown inside canvas?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have a canvas positioned on the right side of the screen.  To the left are some buttons.  If x values of some drawbles are negative, they are drawn on the left side, outside of the canvas.  How can I avoid it?

```
Row {
    Button(onClick = {
    }) {
        Text("File")
    }
    Canvas(modifier = ...) {
        drawPoints(dataPts, PointMode.Points, Color.Blue, strokeWidth = 5f)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, all Compose views do not clip their content outside the boundaries.

You can add [`Modifier.clipToBounds`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/draw/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).clipToBounds()) when you need to clip it:

```
Canvas(Modifier.clipToBounds())
```

Or you can use [`Modifier.clip`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/draw/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).clip(androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape)) to clip to a specific shape.